# How to get the active window's title with AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote this short test code, but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
F12::
WinGetTitle, Title, A ;
MsgBox, "%Title%"
```

The displayed result was ""

Comment: You simply need a space in front of the `;` for it to work, without the space the `;` is taken as part of the windows title

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I removed a ; and added return and this worked...

```
F12::
WinGetTitle, title, A
MsgBox, "%title%"
return
```

Answer (score 6):

The best practice would probably be to use [WinGetActiveTitle](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetActiveTitle.htm):

```
F12::
   WinGetActiveTitle, Title
   MsgBox, The active window is "%Title%".
return
```

Comment: note the output cointains also the program name see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56165323/2043349

Answer (score 3):

If you do not put in a return it will run down your whole file.

Probably something not running through later in it.

Don't think the ; will affect it.

Anything **after** a ; is omitted from code as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In AutoHotKey 2 you can use this:

```
title := WinGetTitle("A")  ; "A" matches "Active" window
```

In AutoHotKey 1 you can use:

```
WinGetActiveTitle, title
```

Answer (score 0):

Using WinGetActiveTitle or WinGetTitle will do.
Note the output of WinGetTitle contains more than the window title.
You might want to remove the ending part with the program name e.g." - Google Chrome".

```
WinGetActiveTitle, Title
StringGetPos,pos,Title,%A_space%-,R
if (pos != -1)
    Title := SubStr(Title,1,pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else want to find the active windows info by `autohotkey`

Just run [`WindowSpy.ahk`](https://amourspirit.github.io/AutoHotkey-Snippit/WindowSpy.html)

The location is in your folder of `AutoHotkey.exe`